# get rows with empty dates pandas python

Tags: python, pandas

it looks like this:

```
      Dates  N-D  unit
0  1/1/2016  Q1   UD
1            Q2   UD
2            Q3   UD
3  2/1/2016  Q4   UD
4  5/1/2016  Q5   UD
5            Q6   UD
```

I want to filter out the empty Dates rows and save it in a dataframe blankDate:

```
      Dates  N-D  unit
1            Q2   UD
2            Q3   UD
5            Q6   UD


 blankDate=df1[df1['Dates']== '']  #this didn't work 
 df1['Discharge Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['Discharge Date']) #then I converted the column to date format but still doesn't work
```

if the column is a string this piece of code works, it also works on numbers I think

```
blankDate=df1[df1['stringcolumn']== '']
```

but how do I compare to empty date rows?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One way would be to replace empty cells by nan and then use isnull()

```
df.Dates = df.Dates.replace('', np.nan)
blankDate = df[df.Dates.isnull()]
```

Answer (score 4):

```
#use pd.isnull to check nans for date type.
df[pd.isnull(pd.to_datetime(df.Dates))]
Out[1512]: 
  Dates N-D unit
1        Q2   UD
2        Q3   UD
5        Q6   UD
```

Comment: That's clever! +1

Comment: Thank you @A-Za-z

Answer (score 1):

Blanks resolve to `False` when cast as Boolean

```
df[~df.Dates.astype(bool)]
```

Comment: good idea, but `TypeError: cannot astype a datetimelike from [datetime64[ns]] to [bool]`