# Pandas Merge and filter

Tags: python, pandas

I used merge to create a dataframe between 2 of my query's.
Now in the dataframe I want to put a filter on a column but I cannot get it to work. I am trying to add filter component date is null or blank.

```
    ##reading data from sql
    package = pd.read_sql(sql,con)
    component = pd.read_sql(sqla,con)

    ##doing the left join
    test2 = pd.merge(package,component, on = ['identifier','date'], how='left')

    ##shrinking the dataframe   
    test3 = test2[['identifier_x']].copy()
```

i've tried doing the below but cannot get it to work. Getting `date_y` not defined. I also tried with just `date`, as when I merge my dataframes the like columns get labelled `x` and `y`.

```
 test2 = pd.merge(package,component, on = ['identifier','date'], how='left'), component.query(date_y == '')
```

Now trying:

```
test2 = pd.merge(package,component, on = ['identifier','date'], how='left')
test2.query('date_y == \'\'')
```

And

```
test2 = pd.merge(package,component, on = ['identifier','date'], how='left')
test2[test2.date_y == '']
```

Also tried:

```
test2 = pd.merge(package,component, on = ['identifier','date'], how='left')
test2 = test2.date_y == ''
```

Sample data:

```
+------------+------------+------------+------------+
|   date_x   | identifier |   date_y   | identifier |
+------------+------------+------------+------------+
| 13/03/2019 | 3582191409 | 13/03/2019 | 3582191410 |
| 13/03/2019 | 3582191289 | 13/03/2019 | 3582191290 |
| 13/03/2019 | 3582190137 | 13/03/2019 | 3582190138 |
| 13/03/2019 | 3582185931 | 13/03/2019 | 3582185930 |
| 13/03/2019 | 3582184503 |            | 3582184502 |
| 13/03/2019 | 3582195631 |            | 3582195632 |
| 13/03/2019 | 3582191374 |            | 3582191373 |
| 13/03/2019 | 3582185917 |            | 3582185916 |
| 13/03/2019 | 3582185863 |            | 3582185862 |
+------------+------------+------------+------------+
```

Im trying to filter date y = blanks

Comment: Have you got your parentheses in the correct places? Just eyeballing it, it seems out.

Comment: @Berenger which parentheses, they seem okay for me.

Comment: In your final `test2`. It's currently set up to create a tuple of two items: the first being your merged DataFrame and the second being a filtered version of `component` (as defined when you read it in from SQL). If you want to filter your merged DataFrame using `pd.query`, you need to use the following on a new line: `test2.query('date_y == \'\'')`. Note with `pd.query` that the whole query needs to be in inverted commas. Equivalently, you could use: `test2[test2.date_y == '']`.

Comment: @Berenger I am trying your suggestions but the filter doesnt seem to be working, Seem my above changes.

Comment: Is it the same error? Suggests the column name on which you are filtering is not right. I notice you are joining on date, so you probably need to drop the _y. But you should verify what your merge produces by looking at test2.head() for example. If you want I can post an answer with arbitrary data.

Comment: @Berenger , actually no error, just no filtering :(.  I write to csv and then the "like" fields come in a date_x and date_y.  Yes please post your answer master.

Comment: Might be useful actually if you post some sample data from component and package.

Comment: @Berenger I posted some sample data, Package file would be date and identifier, same with component, when merged they  are automatically named x and y.

Comment: @Berenger you there?

Comment: yeah sorry, I’m away from the computer for about a week. Is sample data what you get from your left join? Seems odd that you have two identifier columns and two date columns if you are joining on them. Either way, the code I suggested would work with that sample data if the blanks are ‘’. Something to try might be set(test2.date_y) to see how the blanks are coded.

Comment: @excelguy If you do `type(test2['date_y'][4])`, what is the output? And also `len(test2['date_y'][4])`?

Comment: @Zionsof the output is `<class 'datetime.date'>`  . As for the Len, it has the type has no len().

Comment: So that's your issue. You're trying to filter strings, but it's no a string - it's a `datetime.date` object. You need to filter by nonempty date object

Comment: @excelguy written an answer for you

Comment: @excelguy could you post a short sample of package and component so we can reproduce your error ?

Comment: Is date_y a timstamp or a string?

Comment: Try passing a `parse_dates` parameter to your `read_sql` calls. This should be a list of columns you want to be datetimes. For this case, it should be `['date_x']` or `['date_y']` (depending on which table you're reading). Then you can filter on nulls instead of figuring out exactly what "empty" string you have in those rows.

Comment: have you tried `test2[test2.date_y.isna()]` or are they just strings not nas

Comment: @Nev1111 it is a datetime.date format.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're most likely reading in blanks.  I would first make sure date_x and date_y are timestamps and replace all blanks with np.nan:

```
test2['date_y']=test2['date_y'].replace(' ',np.nan)
test2['date_x']=pd.to_datetime(test2['date_x'])
test2['date_y']=pd.to_datetime(test2['date_y'])
test2_filtered=test2.loc[test2['date_y'].isnull()]
```

Comment: Thanks Nev, this worked. Can you explain what you did?

Comment: Sure, what I did was I re-created the dataframe you posted making sure each of the blanks in the 'date_y' field is filled with a blank (" ") character.  Then I replaced the blank characters with a null/nan (or nothing). (line 1)  Then in lines 2 & 3, I used pd.to_datetime to convert the type of the data contained in both 'date_x' and 'date_y' fields to a datestamp.  And at the end, I just filtered out the nulls(the fields that contain nothing).  Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to filter strings, but it's not a string - it's a empty `datetime.date` object. You need to filter by nonempty date object.

You can create a second dataframe as string type and check then:

```py
str_test2 = test2.astype(str)
filtered_test2 = test2[str_test2['date_y'] != '']
```

See more possible solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44123530/get-rows-with-empty-dates-pandas-python)

Comment: thanks! For some reason it is not filtering though, code runs fine. But when I output filtered_test2 still have my blanks in date_y.

Comment: Weird. None of the other answers in the thread I linked to helped as well?

Comment: Great! :) Glad I could help